# How can I use awk to continously read a file as it grows?

Tags: awk

I am working with an awk script and trying to follow the content of a file that grows, until I get a message that all is up and running. The problem is that I do not know how long it will take until everything is started and until then I need to read all the new content in the same file.

The problem with using getline, is that it will return when it reaches EOF, so it will not wait for new output. Any idea how to keep reading when new output is added in awk? I am looking for something similar to `tail -f`.

BR

Patrik

EDIT:

 As it does not seem to be clear to everyone that I am working with an awk script and not in bash, I want to comment on this again. It looks something like,

```
#awk code
#awk code
...
#awk code
#Do something here to be able to imitate tail -f
#more awk code
```

Comment: `I am looking for something similar to tail -f` So why not just _use_ `tail -f`? `tail -f file | awk ....`

Comment: You are looking for `tail -f`. Just `tail -f startup.log | awk 'whatever'` will allow you do what you want -- so long as your `startup.log` is being written to 1-line at a time.

Comment: @KamilCuk This is not convenient, as I then would have to do something like, `awk -f script.awk; #read output from awk; tail -f $output; awk -f second_script.awk`. This is why I wrote I was working with an awk script, so it is all initiated from awk (or gawk really).

Comment: I do not understand - what is not convenient? Why your commend uses two scripts? Use `tail -f file | awk -f script`. You can do `awk -f script <(tail -f file)`

Comment: @KamilCuk As I said, I do have a lot of awk code already, from the awk script I am working on. It would be inconvenient to start a taile process just to pipe the content to another awk process.

Comment: `#Do something here to be able to imitate tail -f` you could spawn tail with like `cmd="tail -f "file; cmd | getline x` I think.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, this will be my backup plan. However, the application will also run on cygwin, so usually we pack it with external applications, though tails might should probably be safe to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use awk (and awk only) to continously read a file as it grows?

Awk has no interface to do that - once it reaches EOF the file is done for. You can write your own extension where you POSIX `open()` the file and block on `read()` from the file to a buffer up until `FS` is received and expose that as an interface to awk (basically same as [tail source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tail.c#L442)). See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Extensions.html .

> How can I use awk to continously read a file as it grows?

You would use it with `awk`.

```
tail -f file | awk 'script'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind awk spinning using up CPU cycles:

```
$ cat waitForTarget.awk
BEGIN {
    file = ARGV[1]
    while ( !found ) {
        while ( (getline < file) > 0 ) {
            if ( index($0,target) ) {
                printf "Found %s\n", target | "cat>&2"
                found = 1
                break
            }
        }
        close(file)
    }
}
```

The above reads the whole input file and if it doesn't find the target string in it then it reads that same input file again and keeps doing so until the target string shows up.

For example:

```
$ cat file
foo
bar

$ awk -v target='Eureka' -f waitForTarget.awk file &
[1] 1461
```

Wait a few seconds just to see that the awk script isn't producing output and then append the target string to the end of the input file:

```
$ echo 'Eureka' >> file
```

and you'll see awk produce this output and stop running:

```
Found Eureka

[1]+  Done                    awk -v target='Eureka' -f waitForTarget.awk file
```

In the above example I ran the awk script in the background just so I could do everything in one window, obviously you don't have to do that and could run the script in the foreground if something else in some other window or in the background is writing to the input file.